# Wordpress how to translae acf plugin fields to another language?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, translation, advanced-custom-fields

I need to translate Choose File & No file chosen to another language (Japanese).

The following code is from `acf` field.

I looked into the code but there are no `Choose File & No file chosen`.

Would you please let me know how to translate them in this case?

[image]

```
<div class="acf-input">
<div class="acf-file-uploader" data-library="all" data-mime_types="" data-uploader="basic">
    <input type="hidden" name="acf[field_60bc51d8898c5]" value="" data-name="id">   <div class="show-if-value file-wrap">
        <div class="file-icon">
            <img data-name="icon" src="" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="file-info">
            <p>
                <strong data-name="title"></strong>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>File name:</strong>
                <a data-name="filename" href="" target="_blank"></a>
            </p>
            <p>
                <strong>filesize:</strong>
                <span data-name="filesize"></span>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="acf-actions -hover">
            <a class="acf-icon -cancel dark" data-name="remove" href="#" title="Delete"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="hide-if-value">     
        <label class="acf-basic-uploader">
            <input type="file" name="acf[field_60bc51d2899c5]" id="acf-field_60bc51d2899c5">
                               </label>             
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to translate just a handful of words and not the entire plugin, then you could use the following method!

So, every **well-developed** plugin/theme has a `text domain` associated with it, so that you could hook into it and manipulate any text generated by that plugin/theme. For example `text domain` for `woocommerce` plugin is `woocommerce`! For `ACF` plugin, it's `acf`!

Usually you could find the `text domain` in the main file of the plugin. For `ACF` plugin you could find it in the `acf.php` located in the root directory of the plugin. See the screenshot below!

[image]

After you found the `text domain` then you could hook into it using `gettext`, `ngettext` etc. `filter hooks`! See the code below:

```php
add_filter('gettext', 'your_theme_translate_acf_fields', 20, 3);

function your_theme_translate_acf_fields($translated, $text, $domain)
{
  if ('acf' == $domain) :
    switch ($translated) {
      case 'No file chosen': // THIS IS THE TEXT GENERATED BY THE ACF PLUGIN
        $translated = 'ファイルが選択されていません';
        break;
      case 'Choose File': // THIS IS THE TEXT GENERATED BY THE ACF PLUGIN
        $translated = 'ファイルを選ぶ';
        break;
    }
  endif;

  return $translated;
}
```

> **Notice:** Capitalization matters!

Code goes to your `functions.php` of your active theme. Tested and works!

> Wordpress translation filter hooks:
> [gettext](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/gettext/)
> [ngettext](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/ngettext/)

Comment: Hi Ruvee: long time no see : ) and thank you for your supportive hlep. I checked acf.php and it was same as your explanation. I also copy and pasted the code in my functions.php but it doesn't translate them. Console shows no error. I'm not sure why it's not working from my side... Would you please let me know any possibilities? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using that field on the client side? or on the admin side of your wordpress?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using that field on the client side, for the frontend.

Comment: Hmmm! That's interesting because it works fine on my end. The only thing i could think of at this moment is to put a conditional check to see whether the text is on the front end of your website. Just replace this `if ('acf' == $domain) :` with `if (!is_admin() && 'acf' == $domain) :`

Comment: Hi Ruvee: Thank you and I tried it but still no changes...

Comment: Make sure that the word is exactly the same as the text generated by `acf`. Exact Capitalization , exact spacing etc.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: I checked Captical letter and I worte exactly the same. And, I found something strange. When I login using admin ID, it shows No file selected & Add File. When I login using a user ID, it shows No file chosen & Choose File. The code translates No file selected & Add File, but doesn't translate No file chosen & Choose File. Would you please let me know what would be the problem?

Comment: So non-admin users see a different field that is not generated by `acf`, now it makes sense, because if the text is generated by `acf`, it'll definitely get translated. The methodology suggested as the answer is correct then. I think you have to change the `acf` global settings so that non-admin users could use the `acf` fields too.

Comment: Hi Ruvee: non-admin users see a different field, but it is generated by acf. The page shows acf field frontend, and I din't add others (I actually don't know how to add the button, the acf field automatically crated it)... That's strange... huh...

Comment: Hi Ruvee : I looked into again but still one acf field displays differnt text for admin and non-admin, I have no idea why is it so... I voted up since it works for admin. In case if you find the solution for the non-admin, I would really appreciate if you could let me know. Thank you for your help all the time and have a nice day Ruvee : )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate any plugin first, check the .pot file. The file is inside wp-content>plugins>plugins-name>languages. You can edit the file with POedit. You can translate to any language.

Comment: Hi codescaptain : thank you for your help. I'm using WPML and check PO file but acf doesn't have it (while other plugins have it). Screenshot=> https://i.imgur.com/0tXtyp1.jpg . Would you please let me know how to deal with the problem in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you can create a topic in https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/advanced-custom-fields/  . I hope you find the solution.